# Ajax передача данных из формы

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Есть такая форма с javascriptoм

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.calc select').change(function(){
        $country = $('select#choose-country').val();
    if ($country == 'austria') {
          $koef = 1;
        }
    if ($country == 'great-britain') {
          $koef = 2;
        }
     if ($country == 'nederland') {
          $koef = 3;
        }
        $totalprice = $koef * 100;
    $('#price').text($totalprice);
         })        
 </script>
```

```html
 <section id="main">
    <form method="post" id="ajax_form" action="" >
    
    <select class="form-control" name="country" id="choose-country">
         <option value="austria">Австрия</option>
         <option value="great-britain">Великобритания</option>
         <option value="nederland">Голландия</option>
    </select>
    
    <div class="price-final">
      <h5>Цена зависит от страны</h5>
      <span name="price" id="price">0</span>EUR</div>
<button id="calc-price" type="button" class="btn-warning">Посчитать</button>
<button id="send-price-to-us" type="submit" class="btn-success">Выслать нам заявку</button>
        
    </form>
   </section>
```

После этого я посылаю данные с помощью Ajax вот так

```html
<script src="https://какой-то.сайт/calc-price/email.js"></script>
```

Скрипт выглядит вот так

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#ajax_form").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/calc-price/e-mail-form/send-form1.php",
      data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
      $(this).find("input, span").val("");
      alert("Спасибо за заявку! Скоро мы с вами свяжемся.");
      $("#ajax_form").trigger("reset");
    });
    return false;
  });
  
});
```

Дальше код класса по отправке имейла выглядит вот так

```html
<?php

$recepient = "myemail@gmail.com";
$sitename = "mypage";

$country = trim($_POST["country"]);
$price = trim($_POST["totalprice"]);
$key_to_txt = array('austria' => 'Австрия');
```

**Теперь вопрос:**
Проблемма в том что мне не приходит переменная $price, тоесть она считается в форме но мне не приходит.
И Названия стран приходят тоже только на латыни. 
Как мне решить проблемму с переводом и с вытягиванием результата с формы?

Comment: А что вы хотели? На форме нет никакого инпута где бы содержалась цена price. А у селекта на сервер приходят данные из аттрибута `value`.

Comment: Можно ли вытягивать данные из span ?

Comment: Естественно можно.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Comment: Существует метод `text()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элемент с name="price" должен быть элементом формы, например input.
Если требуется чтобы него нельзя было редактировать тогда использовать readonly.
Также можно его свертать так что это будет как обычный текст. Ну или на худой конец держать span и hidden input.

Comment: А как передать значение value в инпут с неким айди? 
Я дописал и у меня вот так не работает 
$('#input-price').val(.text($price);

Comment: тут синтаксическая ошибка: $('#input-price').val(.text($price);

Comment: Нужно указать jquery объект:
$('#input-price').val($('#price').text($price));

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за советы.
Добавил возле значения скрытый input

```html
<input name="emailprice" id='price' class='hidden' value=''>
```

Передал в value переменную дописав строку кода

```js
$('#price').val($totalprice);
```

И дописал в php строку кода

```js
$price = trim($_POST["emailprice"])
```

Все работает.
Спасибо за советы.